# Airflow packaged DAGs won't work if installed modules add .py file on top-level of the zip file

Tags: python, airflow

I'm setting up a multi-user airflow cluster for a team of data-scientists, with various usages for the DAGs (ETL, NLP, ML, NN...), some of them having specific python dependencies.
I can't simply add all the DAGs dependencies at system level. Of course, I can setup a baseline for common uses, but for specific needs it's gonna be very helpful to rely on that zipped DAG feature.

So, in order to address that multi-context problem, I'm testing the [packaged DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#packaged-dags) feature of Airflow 1.9.0 (on Ubuntu 16.04).

I'm following the example to test it with an arbitrary pypi package.

- I randomly picked a python module (python-crontab). (prior to this I tried with more beefy modules but it took longer to reproduce the tests)
- test scenario: being able to import that module and print its version in a zipped DAG
- here's the way I did it:

  ```
  $ virtualenv venv --python=python3
  $ source venv/bin/activate
  (venv) $ mkdir contents && cd contents
  $ pip install --install-option="--install-lib=$PWD" python-crontab
  $ cp ../my_dag.py .
  $ zip -r ../test_zip_2.zip *
  $ cp ../test_zip_2.zip /path/to/dags
  $ journalctl -f -u airflow-scheduler.service
  (...)
  WARNING - No viable dags retrieved from /path/to/dags/test_zip_2.zip
  ```
- contents of my DAG:

  ```
  import crontab
  import airflow.utils.dates as a_dates
  from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
  from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
  from airflow.models import DAG

  from pprint import pprint

  args = {
      'owner': 'airflow',
      'start_date': a_dates.days_ago(1)
  }

  def print_context(ds, **kwargs):
      pprint(kwargs)
      print(ds)
      print(crontab.__version__)
      return 'Whatever you return gets printed in the logs'

  with DAG(dag_id='test_zip', default_args=args, schedule_interval=None) as dag:
      (
          PythonOperator(
              task_id='print_the_context',
              provide_context=True,
              python_callable=print_context,
          )
          >> DummyOperator(
              task_id='do_nothing'
          )
      )
  ```

After checking [the code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/models.py#L304), it appears that the logic that parses the ZIP file exits immediately if it finds a .py file that doesn't contain the words "DAG" and "airflow".

Problem is, that the method I described above actually generates other .py files at root of the archive.

```
$ ll
total 100
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   442 Jun  1 14:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   306 Jun  1 15:30 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  3904 Dec 30  2015 cronlog.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 44651 May 25 16:44 crontab.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  4438 Dec 28  2015 crontabs.py
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   476 Jun  1 14:26 dateutil/
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  6148 Jun  1 14:24 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   204 Jun  1 14:26 __pycache__/
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   272 Jun  1 14:26 python_crontab-2.3.3-py3.5.egg-info/
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   306 Jun  1 14:26 python_dateutil-2.7.3-py3.5.egg-info/
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   238 Jun  1 14:26 six-1.11.0-py3.5.egg-info/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 30888 Sep 17  2017 six.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   832 Jun  1 14:48 my_dag.py
```

Many of the well-known packages I tested generate these top-level .py files though. Eg. installing scrapy, numpy, pandas, etc generated the same mess.

So, what could be my options (without forking airflow ^_^)?

Do I correctly understand this feature?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note: the PythonVirtualEnvOperator doesn't address this case. Some of my jobs are needing heavy libraries, and this operator generates on-the-fly disposable virtualenv's at every run, adding many minutes of delay for each execution.

Comment: Isn't installing packages more a job for "the usual suspects" like Terraform, Ansible, Puppet and so on and the zip files just and only for Airflow contents?

Comment: @tobi6 that's the idea: I'm using puppet for the shared modules. But  for data scientists unfamiliar with puppet and other internal operational tools in my company, having the opportunity to test a DAG with a new module without the need for devops' help would be a huge win.

Comment: After further thinking about it, I see a possibility to handle these 3rd party modules in an elegant way: patching Airflow to support a different tree structure in the zipped DAG. rough idea:
pip installs would be done in a subfolder...

zip contents:

       ./a_dag.py

       ./modules

       ./modules/module1/

       ./modules/module2/...

Answer (score 2):

For those who reached this article *now* should follow the updated instruction below, as of v1.10.3.

> Note
>
> When searching for DAGs, Airflow only considers python files that contain the strings "airflow" and "DAG" by default. To consider all python files instead, disable the `DAG_DISCOVERY_SAFE_MODE` configuration flag.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/docs/concepts.rst#dags

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/UPDATING.md#new-dag_discovery_safe_mode-config-option-1

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The fix has been merged into version 1.10-stable, should no longer happen.

Unfortunately it looks like what you want is not going to be possible as of the current state of the code.

I've made a pull request on this issue [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3505/commits/d486df4ac8ddb5f233830ebe742ab6b692354e22) in Apache Airflow's GitHub; if you're interested in following along.